# How can I unit test a retryWhen operator in rxjs?

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs, retrywhen

I am attempting to unit test a custom RxJS operator. The operator is very simple, it uses RetryWhen to retry a failed HTTP request, but has a delay and will only retry when the HTTP Error is in the 500 range. Using jasmine, and this is in an Angular application.

I've looked at this:

[rxjs unit test with retryWhen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861584/rxjs-unit-test-with-retrywhen)

Unfortunately, updating the SpyOn call doesn't seem to change the returned observable on successive retries. Each time it retries it is retrying with the original spyon Value.

I have also looked at a bunch of rxjs marble examples, none of which seem to work. I am not sure it is possible to use rxjs marbles here, because (AFAIK) there is no way to simulate a situation where you first submit an errored observable, then submit a successful observable on subsequent tries.

The code is basically a clone of this: 
https://blog.angularindepth.com/retry-failed-http-requests-in-angular-f5959d486294

```
export function delayedRetry(delayMS: number, maxRetry) {
    let retries = maxRetry;

    return (src: Observable<any>) =>
        src.pipe(
            retryWhen((errors: Observable<any>) => errors.pipe(
                delay(delayMS),
                mergeMap(error =>
                    (retries-- > 0 && error.status >= 500) ? of(error) : throwError(error))

            ))
        );
}
```

I would like to be able to demonstrate that it can subscribe to an observable that returns an error on the first attempt, but then returns a successful response. The end subscription should show whatever success value the observable emits.

Thank you in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 5):

try use this observable as source observable to test

```
const source = (called,successAt)=>{
  return defer(()=>{
  if(called<successAt){
    called++
  return throwError({status:500})
  }
  else return of(true)
  })
  }
```

test

```
this.delayedRetry(1000,3)(source(0,3)).subscribe()
```

Comment: that helped me out, I didn't know you could do that with the source, cool.

Answer (score 2):

To test the retry functionality, you need a observable which emits different events each time you call it. For example:

```
let alreadyCalled = false;
const spy = spyOn<any>(TestBed.inject(MyService), 'getObservable').and.returnValue(
  new Observable((observer) => {
    if (alreadyCalled) {
      observer.next(message);
    }
    alreadyCalled = true;
    observer.error('error message');
  })
);
```

This observable will emit an error first and after that a next event.

You can check, if your observable got the message like this:

```
it('should retry on error', async(done) => {
    let alreadyCalled = false;
    const spy = spyOn<any>(TestBed.inject(MyDependencyService), 'getObservable').and.returnValue(
      new Observable((observer) => {
        if (alreadyCalled) {
          observer.next(message);
        }
        alreadyCalled = true;
        observer.error('error message');
      })
    );
    const observer = {
      next: (result) => {
        expect(result.value).toBe(expectedResult);
        done();
      }
    }

    subscription = service.methodUnderTest(observer);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on a previous answer I have been using this, which gives you more control over what's returned.

```
const source = (observables) => {
  let count = 0;
  return defer(() => {
    return observables[count++];
  });
};
```

Which can then be used like this

```
const obsA = source([
  throwError({status: 500}),
  of(1),
]);
```

Or it can then be used with rxjs marbles like

```
const obsA = source([
  cold('--#', null, { status: 500 }),
  cold('--(a|)', { a: 1 }),
]);
```